# Change author of commit on GitHub and Pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm, commit, git-merge

I started using Pycharm recently for a project. I have linked my GitHub account so I could commit directly in my repos. However the author name of the commits is not the username I have on GitHub.

I used `git config --global user.name "New Name"` in Pycharm so now the author is correctly set up but **how do I change the author name on merged branches?** Especially when I have things like this:

[image: Branches example, merged commits]

I also tried `git rebase -i -p [commit hash]` following this [tutorial](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email) but I get
`fatal: --preserve-merges was replaced by --rebase-merges Note: Your 'pull.rebase' configuration may also be set to 'preserve', which is no longer supported; use 'merges' instead`.

Comment: To change authors, you should change the entire history. Which it is very bad if other users (or in general repositories) were created from old history. Just do not do it. Thing changes, and people are expected not to trust old email addresses (or to see weird names). It is normal in git (and it is a "feature": we freeze time, so no tampering).

Comment: The thing is, I wanted to change the name because it uses my real name from my pycharm profile instead of github one, and I didn't want to doxx myself basically.